# Extract points from PointCloud with PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm using the library PCL to read .pcd point clouds.
I need to extract a profile cut of this point cloud.
Any idea advice on how to implement such a feature ?

Basically, I want to move a box along the point cloud, and project the points present in the box on 1 plane.

I already did the reading of the point cloud, but I'm a bit stuck with the extraction of sub-point cloud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pcl::ProjectInliers` class which does exactly that: it projects the points onto a parametric model (e.g. plane, sphere, ...). There's even an [handy tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/project_inliers.php) for it!

Here's an extract from the tutorial which creates a plane and projects the points on it:

```
  // Create a set of planar coefficients with X=Y=0,Z=1
  pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients ());
  coefficients->values.resize (4);
  coefficients->values[0] = coefficients->values[1] = 0;
  coefficients->values[2] = 1.0;
  coefficients->values[3] = 0;

  // Create the filtering object
  pcl::ProjectInliers<pcl::PointXYZ> proj;
  proj.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
  proj.setInputCloud (cloud);
  proj.setModelCoefficients (coefficients);
  proj.filter (*cloud_projected);
```

Comment: I managed to project my point cloud on the plane, but not sure I understood the following answer to get only a buffer of a small distance around my plane
Can I still use the planar coefficients for that  ?

Comment: You can use [CropHull](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_crop_hull.html) to filter the points within a region of your choice. Then use the output for the projection.

Comment: The link for the tutorial has expired. The new link is: https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/project_inliers.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an actual box but a distance threshold to a plane will do try this.

plane can be represented by a unit normal vector (3d) and distance, say norm = (0,0,1), d = 10. This defines a plane z = 10;

create a point on the plane, just (10*0, 10*0, 10*1) -> point_on_plane =(0,0,10)

point distance from plane  dist = (p - point_on_plane) .dot(norm)

if fabs(dist) less than threshold, project points on the plane
projection = p - dist*norm

to iterate all cross section increase d.